# Is is possible to use navigation.toggleDrawer() in navigation options

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5

In my navigation file , when I want to toggle drawer , get the following error :

> TypeError: navigation.openDrawer is not a function.(In
>   'navigation.openDrawer()', 'navigation.openDrawer' is undefined)

This is my drawer:

```
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
            initialRouteName="MYSHIFT"
        >
            <Drawer.Screen name="MYSHIFT" component={TopTabNavigator} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}
```

And this is my container navigation :

```
const CareworkerNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>

                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Login"
                    component={LoginScreen}
                    options={{ headerShown: false }} />

                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Main"
                    options={({ navigation }) => {
                        return {
                            headerLeft: () => <Button title="LEFT BUTTON" onPress={() => {
                                navigation.toggleDrawer(); // <--- this line throws an error 
                            }} />
                        }
                    }}
                    component={DrawerNavigator} />

            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default CareworkerNavigation
```

Why I can not use navigation.toggleDrawer() in navigation options? 
Is is possible to remove this problem ?

Comment: Navigation is an object. Can you try wrapping it like this ({navigation})=>{} ?

Comment: It was an error while typing.  but I get the same error

Answer (score 7):

If you check the React Navigation docs, "You will need to make the drawer navigator the parent of any navigator where the drawer should be rendered on top of its UI."

[React Navigation docs reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#nesting-drawer-navigators-inside-others)

To answer your question : Yes , it is possible.

And here you have a working example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Button, View } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

const Feed = () => <View />
const Notifications = () => <View />
const Profile = () => <View />

const FeedStack = createStackNavigator()

const Home = ({ navigation }) => (
    <FeedStack.Navigator>
        <FeedStack.Screen
            name="Feed"
            component={Feed}
            options={props => {
                const { toggleDrawer } = props.navigation // <-- drawer's navigation (not from stack)
                return {
                    headerLeft: () => <Button title="LEFT BUTTON" onPress={toggleDrawer} />
                }
            }}
        />
    </FeedStack.Navigator>
)

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

export default props => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Feed">
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="Feed"
            component={Home}
            options={{ drawerLabel: 'Home' }}
          />
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="Notifications"
            component={Notifications}
            options={{ drawerLabel: 'Updates' }}
          />
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={Profile}
            options={{ drawerLabel: 'Profile' }}
          />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While constructing `navigation` at `options`, you refer to the `navigation` of the stack, what cant perform draw actions, try to construct it on header itself

---

```
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Main"
                options={() => {
                    return {
                        headerLeft: (navigation) => <Button title="LEFT BUTTON" onPress={() => {
                            navigation.toggleDrawer(); // <--- this line throws an error 
                        }} />
                    }
                }}
                component={DrawerNavigator} />
```

---

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/55

Comment: Thanks -I modified my code according to your answer, but I get the same error again (``undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.toggleDrawer')``)

Comment: can you try please replace `headerLeft` with `header` for check it, and if still don't work maybe upload your code o sandbox?

Comment: I replaced ``headerLeft`` with ``header`` but I get the same error again. I will upload my code on the sandbox . let you know, thanks in advance